# Wordpress Configuration with SELinux on CentOS 8

Tags: php

My VPS is running with CentOS 8. I installed there Wordpress for my website. After finishing setup of my website, I cannot download/update plugin or theme. I got a solution by disabling SELinux for permanently.But, it's really an idiotic work. Here is a log file of SELinux alert.

I cannot understand, should I allow these things?
LOGS:
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from using the execmem access on a process.
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from write access on the directory wp-content.
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 80.

I just tried one of them to solve:
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from write access on the directory wp-content.

by
`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/path/wp-content'`

`restorecon -v 'path/wp-content'`

But after, allowing this, still I'm getting SElinux preventing error. Nothing solve for my site.
I also tried by allowing main directory of my website/Wordpress by using semanage as well as chcon. Nothing happened good. Did I do anything worn? or what should I do now to solve SELinux permission error for my website.

TIA
It'll be grateful for me if I'll get help from you.

Comment: I am just here to watch. Hope someone can answer this question. I usually fight with SELINUX on CentOS to get minimal functionality. Often turning it off; which is probably not the best approach. LOL :P

Answer (score 1):

Your `restorecon` command is missing the `-R` flag for recursion, that's why it didn't work.

When you ran `restorecon -v 'path/wp-content'`, the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` context only applied to the `wp-content` directory itself, not its contents - namely here the `plugins` and `themes` subdirectories - that's why they remained unwritable.

To fix it, just run `restorecon -Rv 'path/wp-content'`.

For more information: